# change part of time x axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, axis

I have data frame like this one:

```
d <- data.frame(time = seq(as.POSIXct("01.01.2014 05:00:01",
                                  format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"),
                       as.POSIXct("02.01.2014 05:00:00",
                                  format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"),
                       length.out = 1440))
d$variable <- rnorm(1440)
```

I made ggplot of `d`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(data = d, aes(time,variable)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%M"),breaks = "1 hour")
```

[image]

I want change part of x axis labels from 00:00 to 05:00 
Instead of this x axis labels I want 24:00 to 29:00.

Is it possible to do this with scale_x_datetime function or may be smth similar to it?

Comment: I don't think you'll have much luck representing dates on a 29-hr clock!  why are you doing that?

Comment: I guess you could replace `time` with a vector of numbers..

Comment: It's TV airtime standart. Broadcasting starts at 05:00  and ends at 4:59 next day. It is convinient for TV buyers to use 5:00:00 - 28:59:59 time format for advertising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you created a new formatter which calculated hours/minutes since a certain day/time like

```
hmsince_format <- function(since) {
    function(x) {
        dt<-as.numeric(difftime(x, since, units="mins"))
        sprintf("%02d:%02d", as.integer(dt %/% 60), as.integer(dt %% 60))
    }
}
```

Basically `hmsince()` is a factory style function that will return a label formatting function. `ggplot` will pass the dates used as axis marks to this inner function via `x`. We then subtract these dates from the `since` date that remains in scope because our function is nested in the factory. We then subtract the two dates from each other and format them as hour:minute.

Then you could do

```
sinceDate <- as.POSIXct("01.01.2014 00:00:00", format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
ggplot(data = d, aes(time,variable)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = hmsince_format(sinceDate ), breaks = "1 hour")
```

that should give you the labels you are after.

Now that i've read why you are doing this, I created an alternate function that you may wish to use should your data span multiple dates

```
tvtime_format<-function() {
    function(x) {
        v<-character(length(x))
        notNA<-!is.na(x)
        lt <- as.POSIXlt(x[notNA])
        hour <- lt$hour
        hour[hour<5] <- hour[hour<5]+24
        min <- lt$min
        v[notNA]<-sprintf("%02d:%02d", hour, min)
        v
    }
}
```

Here is it not required to pass any particular date to use as an anchor. It will just add 24 to hours less than 5. (I don't really need a nested function in this case but I kept it this way so the methods are similar.) This is used like

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(time,variable)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = tvtime_format(), breaks = "1 hour")
```

Comment: I had a suspicion that my scepticism would prove unfounded.  well done!

Comment: I've added further description and i've also added an alternate formatter that doesn't require an explicit start date.